# Python regex to parse '@####' text in description field

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Here's the line I'm trying to parse:

```
@abc def@gmail.com @ghi j@klm @nop.qrs @tuv
```

And here's the regex I've gotten so far:

```
@[A-Za-z]+[^0-9. ]+\b | @[A-Za-z]+[^0-9. ]
```

My goal is to get ['@abc', '@ghi', '@tuv'], but no matter what I do, I can't get 'j@klm' to not match. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `re.findall` with the following regex pattern:

```
(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\s))@[A-Za-z]+(?=\s|$)

inp = "@abc def@gmail.com @ghi j@klm @nop.qrs @tuv"
matches = re.findall(r'(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\s))@[A-Za-z]+(?=\s|$)', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['@abc', '@ghi', '@tuv']
```

The regex calls for an explanation.  The leading lookbehind `(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\s))` asserts that what precedes the `@` symbol is either a space or the start of the string.  We can't use a word boundary here because `@` is not a word character.  We use a similar lookahead `(?=\s|$)` at the end of the pattern to rule out matching things like `@nop.qrs`.  Again, a word boundary alone would not be sufficient.

Comment: This worked like a charm, and the explanation is a great bonus. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just add the line initiation match at the beginning:

```py
^@[A-Za-z]+[^0-9. ]+\b | @[A-Za-z]+[^0-9. ]
```

it shoud work!

Comment: Unfortunately when I run this, I get:
['`@abc` ', ' `@ghi`', ' `@nop`', ' `@tuv`']